# Angular service inheritance using Object.create()

Tags: javascript, angularjs, oop, inheritance, factory

I'm trying to use inheritance in angular services, as explained here:
http://blog.mgechev.com/2013/12/18/inheritance-services-controllers-in-angularjs/, I want to use the  "Inject the parent" method.

However, it doesn't seem to work, and I can't see why.

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);

angular.module('myApp').controller('MyCtrl', MyCtrl);
angular.module('myApp').factory('BaseModel', BaseModel);
angular.module('myApp').factory('ThreadModel', ThreadModel);
angular.module('myApp').factory('PostModel', PostModel);

function MyCtrl($scope, ThreadModel, PostModel) {
  $scope.tableNameForThreads = ThreadModel.getTableName();
  $scope.tableNameForPosts = PostModel.getTableName();
}

function BaseModel() {
  var tableName = "";

  var service = {
    init: init,
    getTableName: getTableName
  };

  return service;

  function getTableName() {
    return tableName;
  }

  function init(theTableName) {
    tableName = theTableName;
  }
}

function ThreadModel(BaseModel) {
  var service = Object.create(BaseModel);
  service.init("threads");
  return service;
}

function PostModel(BaseModel) {
  var service = Object.create(BaseModel);
  service.init("posts");
  return service;
}
```

The result is that ThreadModel.getTableName() returns "posts" in stead of "threads".

I tried both `Object.create(...)` and `angular.copy(BaseModel, this)`, but both don't seem to make a deep copy.

JSFIDDLE: http://jsfiddle.net/dirkpostma/Lvc0u55v/3989/

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Try to put controller after factories, at your initialization on top

Comment: It's because `init()` always changes `tableName` in the prototype of `BaseModel`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that with this set up using `Object.create` you produce services with the `tableName` variable stored in the same common closure (BaseModel function). To put it simply, `init` method modifies the *same* local `tableName` variable.

You could fix it like this:

```
function BaseModel() {

  var service = {
    init: init,
    getTableName: getTableName
  };

  return service;

  function getTableName() {
    return this._tableName;
  }

  function init(theTableName) {
    this._tableName = theTableName;
  }
}
```

Note, that `getTableName` and `init` methods now work with instance property `this._tableName` which is not shared between `TableModel` and `PostModel` instances.

**Demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/Lvc0u55v/3991/

Answer (score 0):

@dfsq has already well explained and given a simple solution. I put here what I am thinking about this issue.

In your code `Object.create(BaseModel)` creates a new object whose prototype is a returned value of `BaseModel` function. In those children models `init` method modifies `tableName` within the local scope of `BaseModel` function. If you replace `tableName` with `this.tableName`, that will work as you expected: both `init`  and `getTableName` methods will actually modify/call `tableName` property of `service` variable within `ThreadModel` or `PostModel` functions. But it looks complicated.

In your case I would like suggest the following service inheritance solution, which would be clearer. There is [an other post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26642174/angularjs-service-inheritance) that can be interesting.

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

angular.module('myApp').controller('MyCtrl', MyCtrl);
angular.module('myApp').service('BaseModel', BaseModel);
angular.module('myApp').service('ThreadModel', ['BaseModel', ThreadModel]);
angular.module('myApp').service('PostModel', ['BaseModel', PostModel]);

function MyCtrl($scope, ThreadModel, PostModel) {
  $scope.tableNameForThreads = ThreadModel.getTableName();
  $scope.tableNameForPosts = PostModel.getTableName();
}

function BaseModel() {
  this.tableName = "";

  this.getTableName = function() {
    return this.tableName;
  }

  this.init = function(theTableName) {
    this.tableName = theTableName;
  }
}

function ThreadModel(BaseModel) {
  angular.extend(ThreadModel.prototype, BaseModel);
  this.tableName = "threads";
}

function PostModel(BaseModel) {
  angular.extend(PostModel.prototype, BaseModel);
  this.tableName = "posts";
}
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Lvc0u55v/3993/